# Why does it tell me that the method content is undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add message replies to this app : https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed

however I keep getting an error: undefined method `content' for this partial below (line 17).

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>

  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method:  :delete,
                                     confirm: "You sure?",
                                     title:   micropost.content %>
  <% end %>

  <span>
  <h>Comments</h>
  <% @micropost.comments.each do |c| %>
    <p>
      <%=h c.content %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  </span>

  <span>
  <%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols => "20", :rows => "2", placeholder: "Compose new comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

this doesnt make any sense because it has no problems with line 2 for example and I dont explicitly define the method content anywhere in my micropost controller or anywhere else. Where should I be defining content and how should I do it?

here is my code for my comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :micropost

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

  validates :micropost_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'comments.created_at DESC'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to call `content` on a Comment, so the Comment model would need to have a `content` instance method.

Line 2 is calling the method on `@micropost`, which looks to be an instance of a different class.

Comment: it looks like its calling it on micropost not @micropost? It is an instance of micropostconroller rather than commentcontroller. but content is not defined in either one. something like def content end I imagine (correct me if Im wrong). So how would I define it in the commentcontroller?

Comment: It's not calling on any instance of a controller -  once you're in the rendered view, the controller's work is done. It's an instance of a model that these methods are being called on. You would want to define `content` on the Comment model, not the controller.

Comment: it seems like  content is defined with validates on the comment model. is this not the case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'defined with validates'.

Comment: ok well is it not defined in my comments model? How would you define content?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's defined on your comment model. If comments need a `content` method, define one on the `Comment` model...